# How do I redirect all Sub folders and directories to the main root excluding files?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Basically I have a CDN setup.

```
/public_html/
index.html

/files/
image/
video/
video2/video2
```

I want to redirect ALL sub folders and directories to the main folder - except file extensions, so if someone loads a file, I want that to load, just so people cant view directories. (I dont want to see a 404 or forbidden message, just want the directory to go to the main page)

It would save me from uploading index.php redirects. Can this be done with .htaccess?

Comment: yes what does your .htaccess looks like?

Comment: I've not done anything to it... just got a WWW remove on

Comment: so you want: /video.mpeg (file someone access in the url) -> /media/video.mpeg (actual file) ?

Comment: No. Basically
www.site.com/files/video.flv is a url that people can view.. i dont want people to see www.site.com/files and see all my files i want that to redirect to www.site.com - problem is i have lots of sub sub folders too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# don't show any files in the folder
IndexIgnore *

ErrorDocument 403 /
ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteEngine On

# disabled user to access directly to the files folder.
RewriteRule ^files(\/?)$ - [F]

# images
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /files/$1.$2 [L]
# video
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)\.(flv|avi|mov)$ /files/$1.$2 [L]
#etc...
```

If you have sub folders, the `(.*)` will automatically use it. Example:

```
http://www.domain.com/image/i.png => /files/i.png

http://www.domain.com/image/sub1/sub2/i.png => /files/sub1/sub2/i.png
```

Here some links that will help you:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/

http://www.bloghash.com/2006/11/beginners-guide-to-htaccess-file-with-examples/

Comment: What happens if I put this in my URL: http://www.domain.com/image/sub1/ or this http://www.domain.com/image/sub1/sub2/

Comment: standard 404 from /image/sub1/ folder. Which I recommend to have a customized 404 and 403 message. 404 for this one, and 403 when someone access directly /files/ (view my updated answer)

Comment: Can we not redirect ALL 404 and 403 instead to the root?

Comment: Absolutely, view my changes

Comment: Thank you so much, any links you can recommend to understand htaccess rules?